# client specific configuration

Tags: silverlight, deployment

I would like to know if it's possible to have my SL application consume configuration specific to client.
I want my application to be located on the local intranet, and clients will have the abillity to change configurations manually - by editing a xml file.
What's the approach i should take in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly build this kind of functionality into your application and store the configuration in Isolated Storage.  See the following for info on working with Isolated Storage:

[Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)

Comment: Can I access a this kind of file (the one that SL uses for the Isolated storage) and edit it in notepad or such?

Comment: That's not really how Isolated Storage is intended to be used.  That being said, you'd have to locate the file on disk, as you don't have control over where Isolated Storage keeps your files.  Once you've located the file, then yes, I guess you could edit it in Notepad or any other text editor.

Comment: my needs are: load file from a KNOWN (and unchanged!) position in the file system - this is done by SL app, and to be able to edit that file in a text editor.

Comment: Sorry, don't think that's going to work as Silverlight doesn't give you that kind of access to the file system.  There's no way to access arbitrary files due to the security limitations imposed by Silverlight.

Comment: ok, so let's say i don't need the ability to access client config file outside of SL app. the isolated storage will be reliable - so if i'm updating it, next time i'll run the app, the data will be updated with last values?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Isolated Storage is persistent, so if you edit the file and save changes, those changes will be there the next time you run your application.